# Angular fetching apis

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

My apis is http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/public/api/areas

my app.component.ts:

```html
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { Post } from './post.model';
import { PostsService } from './posts.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  loadedPosts: Post[] = [];
  isFetching = false;
  error = null;
  private errorSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private postsService: PostsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.errorSub = this.postsService.error.subscribe(errorMessage => {
      this.error = errorMessage;
    });

    this.isFetching = true;
    this.postsService.fetchPosts().subscribe(
      posts => {
        this.isFetching = false;
        this.loadedPosts = posts;
      },
      error => {
        this.isFetching = false;
        this.error = error.message;
      }
    );
  }

  onCreatePost(postData: Post) {
    // Send Http request
    this.postsService.createAndStorePost( postData.id, postData.name, postData.domain, postData.description , postData.picture);
  }

  onFetchPosts() {
    // Send Http request
    this.isFetching = true;
    this.postsService.fetchPosts().subscribe(
      posts => {
        this.isFetching = false;
        this.loadedPosts = posts;
      },
      error => {
        this.isFetching = false;
        this.error = error.message;
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  onClearPosts() {
    // Send Http request
    this.postsService.deletePosts().subscribe(() => {
      this.loadedPosts = [];
    });
  }

  onHandleError() {
    this.error = null;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.errorSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

my posts.service.ts

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpParams,
  HttpEventType
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject, throwError } from 'rxjs';

import { Post } from './post.model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PostsService {
  error = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  createAndStorePost( id: string,
                      name: string,
                      description: string,
                      domain: string,
                      picture: any ) {
    const postData: Post = {   id  , domain , name, description, picture   };
    this.http
      .post<{ name: string , description: string , domain: string ,  picture: string }>(
        'http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas',
        postData,
        {
          observe: 'response'
        }
      )
      .subscribe(
        responseData => {
          console.log(responseData);
        },
        error => {
          this.error.next(error.message);
        }
      );
  }

  fetchPosts() {
    let searchParams = new HttpParams();
    searchParams = searchParams.append('print', 'pretty');
    searchParams = searchParams.append('custom', 'key');

    return this.http
      .get<{ [key: string]: Post}>(
        'http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas',
        {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Custom-Header': 'Hello' }),
          params: searchParams,
          responseType: 'json'
        }
      )
      .pipe(
        map(responseData => {
          const postsArray: Post[] = [];
          for (const key in responseData) {
            if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              postsArray.push({ ...responseData[key], id: key });
            }
          }
          return postsArray;
        }),
        catchError(errorRes => {
          // Send to analytics server
          return throwError(errorRes);
        })
      );
  }

  deletePosts() {
    return this.http
      .delete('http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas', {
        observe: 'events',
        responseType: 'text'
      })
      .pipe(
        tap(event => {
          console.log(event);
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.Sent) {
            // ...
          }
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            console.log(event.body);
          }
        })
      );
  }
}
```

my posts.model.ts

```html
export interface Post {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  domain: string;
  description: string;
  picture: any;
}
```

my logging-interceptor.service.ts

```html
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEventType
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class LoggingInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    console.log('Outgoing request');
    console.log(req.url);
    console.log(req.headers);
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap(event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          console.log('Incoming response');
          console.log(event.body);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

my auth-interceptor.service.ts

```html
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler
} from '@angular/common/http';

export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const modifiedRequest = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.append('Auth', 'xyz')
    });
    return next.handle(modifiedRequest);
  }
}
```

my app-routing.module.ts

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

my app.module.ts

```html
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthInterceptorService } from './auth-interceptor.service';
import { LoggingInterceptorService } from './logging-interceptor.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: LoggingInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

my app.component.spec.ts

```html
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'ng-complete-guide-update'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('ng-complete-guide-update');
  });

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Welcome to ng-complete-guide-update!');
  });
});
```

my app.component.html

```html
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'ng-complete-guide-update'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('ng-complete-guide-update');
  });

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Welcome to ng-complete-guide-update!');
  });
});
```

my app.component.css

```html
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.row {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

I am only getting data not elements [id ,name,description,domain,picture]why??

Comment: what's inside data? Just posting files related to your problem is enough.

Comment: hi hammad ashraf can you share the proper my app.component.html which is having my app.component.ts file only

Comment: @Ramesh please see the api !!

Comment: hope this helps: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I5EKpssltwf6gvwrwRRK30aEvFxmKWs2dcgeUCyu1WI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Hammad, it will be helpful if you can create reproduce the issue in stackblitz and share with us.

Comment: @GaganV https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I5EKpssltwf6gvwrwRRK30aEvFxmKWs2dcgeUCyu1WI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Because you are getting an array wrapped with data property. You should use `responseData.data` to access that array in your `posts.service.ts`

Comment: @Eldar it again just displaying only data array not its elements !!

Comment: @hammadashraf the response is an object which has a data property and this data is an array of objects which have id, name, description, domain, picture. If you want to access the first element inside the array you can use response.data[0] and so on.